# How can I avoid memory leaks when I implement canvas.drawBitmap method?

Tags: java, android, canvas, memory-leaks, bitmap

I am using the canvas.drawBitmap method quite a bit. And it is cause the application to throw nullpointerexceptions at random occurrences. Is there a way to implement it, such that the drawing will render properly? 
I am creating a board which consists of cells. And cells conists of pixel coordinates of where the image should be. However as mentioned above, not all the images are being shown up. 
I get an error, specifically on  `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, srcRect, dstRect, paint)`.

ERROR:

```
03-18 13:46:21.615  22880-22932/com.example.sam.matrix E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: Game Thread
    Process: com.example.sam.matrix, PID: 22880
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.sam.matrix.framework.util.Painter.drawImage(Painter.java:54)
            at com.example.sam.matrix.game.state.PlayState.renderCell(PlayState.java:74)
            at com.example.sam.matrix.game.state.PlayState.renderBoard(PlayState.java:48)
            at com.example.sam.matrix.game.state.PlayState.render(PlayState.java:38)
            at com.example.sam.matrix.main.GameView.updateAndRender(GameView.java:109)
            at com.example.sam.matrix.main.GameView.run(GameView.java:130)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: Where did you initialize `canvas` in `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dstRect, paint);`?

Comment: In my Painter class, as public class Painter {
    private Canvas canvas;

Comment: Where did you **initialize** `canvas`? This --> `private Canvas canvas;` is the **declaration** of `canvas`, not its **initialization**. You should be looking for something like `canvas = new Canvas();`

Comment: I Updated the painter class.

Comment: Where do you call the constructor `public Painter(Canvas canvas)` in your code?

Comment: Which is line 54 in `Painter.drawImage(Painter.java:54)`

Comment: In my painter class, in my drawImage method
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dstRect, paint);

Comment: I am suspecting that your `public GameView(Context context, int gameWidth, int gameHeight)` constructor is never called. It is calling default constructor. Can you debug your code and check does your code executes your defined constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you debug this line --> `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dstRect, paint);` to figure out what is null. I can see that you initialized `dstRect` and `paint`, so I don't think those would have the null pointer problem. To debug it, you could do something like:

```
if (canvas == null) {
    Log.i("canvas", "canvas is null");
}

if (bitmap == null) {
    Log.i("bitmap", "bitmap is null");
}

canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, null, dstRect, paint);
```

That should tell you what is causing the null pointer exception.

Let me know if this helps.